Diffuse light intensity on a tilted plane
Let's say, I place a horizontal plane under a sky which is the source of homogeneous, diffuse light. My sensor tells me that the intensity of light on the horizontal plane is 100 W/m2. What would the intensity of light be on a tilted plane (at some angle from horizontal, call it $v$)?

When it comes to estimating isotropic sky diffuse radiation on a tilted plane, it is most common to use the view factor (1 + cos s) / 2.
Where s is the tilt of the plane relative to horizontal. As others have pointed out, when the tilt angle is 0°, all the available isotropic diffuse is received. And when the tilt and is 90°, half of the isotropic diffuse is received
This equation for isotropic diffuse on a tilted plane is commonly attributed to a landmark paper from Liu and Jordan (1960). However, a recent work has contested that Liu and Jordan are not actually the original author's of this equation (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.solener.2020.02.067).
It's important to point out that that circumsolar diffuse (ie the annulus around the sun) and horizon brightening diffuse are both important components to consider when modeling sky diffuse radiation on clear sky days, and that there is no consensus on how to model sky diffuse radiation. Noorian et al., 2008 looked at 12 common models for sky diffuse radiation, which is worth a read (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.renene.2007.06.027).
For what it's worth, the solar industry standard for sky diffuse modeling has become the Perez 1990 model which accounts for the isotropic, circumsolar and horizon brightening components, and has been implemented in python in the pvlib package (https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/pvlib.irradiance.perez.html)

Suppose your sensor is a square with a side of $1$ meter and is illuminated by a beam that just covers it. At normal incidence, the power falling on it is $100$ W.
Tilt your sensor $60^o$. $sin(60^0) = 1/2$. Now only half the beam hits the sensor. The sensor measures $50$ W/m$^2$.

The sensor in OP's question is not "illuminated by a beam." It is illuminated by light rays coming from every direction under a hemispherical sky. If we turn OP's "horizontal plane" through 90 degrees so that it is vertical, it still will see half of the sky. It won't see zero incident sky light until we turn it through a full 180 degrees so that it is horizontal, and facing the ground. (and of course, even then, it won't see zero light unless we assume the ground to be perfectly black.)

Oops. Careless reading.

Yes. So when it sees half of the sky (standing vertically) will it receive 50 W/m2 on each side? It must be so but what about other angles? The problem for me is that when I measure 100 W/m2 on the horizontal plane, that is the summation over all incident angles. Beams from any angle will have a weight of sin(u). I cannot make up my mind, whether this question is dead simple or requires some thoughtful integration. We know the integral over the full sky is 100 W/m2, so what is the integral from, say, 0 to 60 degrees (and from 60 to 180 on the other side)? Is this too convoluted a rationale?
